# Why does Node hang when using deasync with x11 events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, x11

I'm trying to use the node modules `deasync` and `x11` to perform actions when certain keys are pressed.

When I use deasync inside a callback that has been initiated by a keypress deasync seems to be stuck in an endless loop.
It works fine if I create a generic event myself.

Run the following script using xtrace to see that X11 does respond:
`xtrace -D :10 ./the-script`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var deasync = require('deasync');
var x11 = require('x11');

var display = (deasync(x11.createClient)());
var client = display.client;

var getInputFocus = deasync(client.GetInputFocus)
    .bind(client);

var focus1 = getInputFocus();
console.log("getting focus here works:", focus1);

// grab the "1"-key - keyCode = 10
client.GrabKey(display.screen[0].root, 0, null, 10, 0, 1);

client.on('event', processKeyPressEvent);

// client.emit("event"); // works

function processKeyPressEvent(event) {
    console.log("can see this");
    var focus2 = getInputFocus(); // problem
    console.log("never get here");
}
```

Thanx for your help.

Comment: I'd really recommend writing all this without `deasync`. That module seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @loganfsmyth confirmed. As the author of this idea, I will regret it eternally

Comment: @vkurchatkin Haha, we all have things we regret writing :)