# Mongodb nodejs driver. Uncalled callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing a MEAN stack on windows10. I created a wrapper helper for mongodb's findAll, gridstore.open and gridstore.write (and almost all of mongodb's functions. These are the only ones i'm having trouble with) that's using deasync so i won't have to pass a callback. And i'm experiencing that my callback functions are not being called! Not always but SOMETIMES. But when I run on Mac, callbacks are always called. ALWAYS.My question is,

1) are there any logs on mongodb why my callbacks are not being called?

2) is it possible that clustered process are handled differently on windows (vs mac) as stated in the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_how_it_works)(please clear it as well) Although before I even implemented clustering, I was already experiencing this issue.

Ps. I'm running on windows 10 and tried receiving and passing via process.send and [this](https://gist.github.com/seriousManual/2909389) seem to happen to me as well.

Here's a code snippet from my MongoDB Helper wrapper

```
exports.FindAll = function(db, collectionName, qObj){
var retVal = [];
var done = false;
var errObj;
if(!qObj)
    qObj = {};

var functionExec = function(err, db){
    var cursorObj = db.collection(collectionName).find(qObj);

    cursorObj.each(function callback(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log("error on DBHelper GetAll");
            console.log(err);
            retVal = err;
            done = true;
            errObj = err;
        }
        if (result == null)
            done = true;
        else
            retVal.push(result);
    });
};
if(!(db.serverConfig.isConnected && db.serverConfig.isConnected()))// || !db.serverConfig.connected)
    db.open(functionExec);
else
    functionExec(undefined, db);
while(!done) 
{
    deasync.runLoopOnce();
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!done){
            console.log("FindAll callback was not called within specified time");
            errObj = new Error("FindAll callback was not called within specified time");
            done = true;
        }
    },5000);
}
if(errObj)
    throw errObj;
return retVal;
```

};

Comment: So you don't have to pass callbacks, yet your callbacks aren't called? Perhaps you should show some code...

Comment: @robertklep here's my helper wrapper.

Comment: So which callback functions aren't being called? Do you mean that your code hits the timeout on Windows?

Comment: Yep. It hits the timeout. Which doesn't happen on mac.

Comment: Maybe its got something to do with deasync? I remember using deasync on fs.write as well. Then ended up using fs.writeSync instead. See this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033837/why-does-node-hang-when-using-deasync-with-x11-events

Comment: To be honest, `deasync` looks like a huge hack. Async isn't _that_ scary (and solutions like [promises](http://blog.apitite.net/2015/08/a-gentle-introduction-to-nodejs.html) make it even less scary).

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I just hope to know why its working fine with mac.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'll have to drop deasync for now. Though it looks like a promising project, there seems to be a problem (a platform dependency on Node/libuv as stated [here](https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/40)) on windows thats running on [mac](https://github.com/abbr/deasync/issues/42)

For now, I'll have to learn to love Nodejs's async nature. And switch every  deasync in my project to promises as suggested by @robertklep